# How do I set a key binding in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I'm making a adventure game in .bat, and I want it so that when the player presses - it takes him to the Map frame and when he presses = the player goes to the Journal. I already worked out a way to return to the frame that the player was originally in, but I need to know how to set up key bindings.
Key bindings are a key that you press at anytime, and when you press it something happens, like you go to a map or teleport.

Comment: You are making a game in batch? This is both beautiful and insane.

Comment: Yes it is, i have already made a very simple one, and I'm trying to make a wikihow on it, but wikihow hates me.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Some example Batch code. To see what you already try.

Comment: I didn't try anything for the key binding, I could show you some code, though.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

Comment: There is no such "key binding" thing in Batch files. You may read input via `set /P input=` and then `if "%input%" equ "-" goto MapFrame`...

Comment: @DavidPostill: `choice` don't allows special characters for input, just letters, digits and foreign characters...

Comment: so `choice 9` would work, like, when I press 9 something would happen, like `choice 9 goto Menu`?

Comment: @EnderScythe: Yes, but you must list _all possible options_ in the `choice` command. Type `choice /?` for furher details. Also, the choice command will wait for a key to be pressed, unless you use the /T switch.

Comment: what is the `choice` variable, is it `choice`

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your last comment. `choice` is a _command_. For further details you may type `choice /?` at the command prompt as I said before, or follow the link posted by DavidPostill above, or search for `batch choice command` here or in Google, or...

Comment: ... or just wait that a compasive user, like @UnknownOctopus, do this job for you and just present the result in an answer ready to be used (avoiding your learning experience) for only 15 rep points... **`:/`**

Comment: After learning for about a year, I have discovered the choice command and figured out how to use it. Your comment was good (even good enough for an answer), but my early mind back in 2015 was too stupid to figure out how to use what you told me.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments your best bet is to use choice. The main setup for choice is:

@choice [/c:] [/n] [/t  /d ] [/m <"Text">]

The /c attribute lists all the available choices (i.e /c:123) would allow 1, 2 or 3 to be pressed.

The /n specifies not to display the inputted choices. (i.e the choices "123" would show up in console as [123]?) For [123]? to be shown leave out the /n

/t sets the time before a default choice is made

/d sets the default choice to be made after /t seconds

/m sets text to be displayed in the console window

For Example:

```
    @ECHO off
    @CHOICE /c:123 /n /t 100 /d 1 /m "TextGoesHere"
    if ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO three
    if ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO two
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO one
    goto end
    :one
    echo You pressed 1!
    echo This is also the default choice after 100 seconds
    goto end
    :two
    echo You pressed 2!
    goto end
    :three
    echo You pressed 3!
    :end
    pause
```

Would display:

```
TextGoesHere [1,2,3]?
```

And if 2 was pressed:

```
TextGoesHere [1,2,3]?
You have pressed "2"!
press any key to continue...
```

And of course you could add code to these sections instead of just displaying text.

For more info about "choice" [click here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php)